# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. even for a small text

Tags: errors, german

I am getting this error message every time. I tried everything I know, this is only a small litter it is not that big... please help me. 
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
  \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}\fi

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[scale=0.775]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\addtolength{\parskip}{6pt}

\def\firstname{Nabil}
\def\familyname{Sifo}
\def\FileAuthor{\firstname~\familyname}
\def\FileTitle{\firstname~\familyname's Bewerbungsschreiben}
\def\FileSubject{Bewerbungsschreiben}
\def\FileKeyWords{\firstname~\familyname, Bewerbungsschreiben}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\hyphenation{ins-be-son-de-re}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{tt}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex,pdfborder=0,breaklinks,baseurl=http://,pdfpagemode=None,pdfstartview=XYZ,pdfstartpage=1]{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{
    pdfauthor   = \FileAuthor,%
    pdftitle    = \FileTitle,%
    pdfsubject  = \FileSubject,%
    pdfkeywords = \FileKeyWords,%
    pdfcreator  = \LaTeX,%
    pdfproducer = \LaTeX}
\else
  \usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}
\fi

\definecolor{firstnamecolor}{RGB}{125,85,85}
\definecolor{familynamecolor}{RGB}{138,74,57}
\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0}

\begin{document}{}
\begin{block}{Blocktitel}
\sffamily   % for use with a résumé using sans serif fonts;
%\rmfamily  % for use with a résumé using serif fonts;
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\textwidth}{}
    \raggedleft%
    {\bfseries {\color{firstnamecolor}\firstname}~{\color{familynamecolor}\familyname}}\\[.35ex]
    \small\itshape%
    Basler Straße 58a\\
    /9100 Freiburg im Breisgau\\[.35ex]
    \Mobilefone~+49 177 1642 709\\
    \Letter~\href{mailto:nabil_Sifo@outlook.com}{nabil_Sifo@outlook.com}
\end{minipage}\\[0.5em]
%
{\color{firstnamecolor}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}{}
    \raggedright%
    % {\bfseries {\color{firstnamecolor}
    \vspace*{1em}
    Allianz SE\\[.35ex]
    % }}
    \small%
    Fritz-Schäffer-Straße 9\\
    81737 München
\end{minipage}
%
\hfill
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
    \raggedleft % US style
    \today
    %April 6, 2006 % US informal style
    %05/04/2006 % UK formal style
\end{minipage}\\[1em]
\raggedright
\begin{block}{}


{\bfseries \color{familynamecolor}Bewerbung als blaaaaaal}\\[1.5em]

Sehr geehrtere Damen und Herren,\\[1em]
%
bla bla \\
blabla


%Yours sincerely,\\[2em] % if the opening is "Dear Mr(s) Doe,"
Mit freundlichen Grüßen,\\[3em] % if the opening is "Dear Sir or Madam,"
%
%\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{signature_blue}\\
{\bfseries \firstname~\familyname}\\
%
\vfill%
{\slshape \bfseries Bewerbungsunterlagen}\\
% {\slshape Curriculum Vit\ae{}}
\end{block}
\end{block}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't load `\usepackage{ngerman}` when you also load `babel`. `\usepackage{ngerman}` is generally considered outdated with `babel` or `polyglossia` the up-to-date replacement. Remove the `\usepackage{ngerman}`.

Comment: Most people don't need `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`. `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (which is the default in LaTeX versions from April 2018 or newer) is enough for most uses.

Comment: The `\ifpdf...\fi` block to load `graphicx` is unnecessary in modern systems. Remove the complete block and just say `\usepackage{graphicx}`. (Similarly `\usepackage[pdftex]{color}` should be `\usepackage{color}`.)

Comment: How or where is the `block` environment defined?

Comment: thank man those tips worked

Comment: Off-topic: If you want to increase the chances that your cv won't be set aside and ignored by whoever you hope will actually read it, do please replace `Sehr geehrtere Damen und Herren` with `Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren`.

Comment: @moewe "modern" here means after 1994 :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop loading the obsolete and deprecated `ngerman` package, which was last updated in 1998, and the `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]` error no longer occurs.

At a minimum, you should further define the `block` environment (possibly by loading a suitable package?), replace `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \addtolength{\parskip}{6pt}` with something like `\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip]{parskip}`, and replace

```
\href{mailto:nabil_Sifo@outlook.com}{nabil_Sifo@outlook.com}
```

with

```
\href{mailto:nabil_Sifo@outlook.com}{\nolinkurl{nabil_Sifo@outlook.com}}
```

Oh, and do yourself a favor and replace

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
  \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}\fi
```

with

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

unless, of course, you treasure code clutter.